# How can you launch dsa.msc programmatically through a button click event in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, active-directory

I am trying to open Active Directory using a button on my application. I don't want to get or set information from or in AD, just open it. The code below gives the error in `System.dll`, which isn't very helpful:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'

Any ideas?

```cs
private void btnAD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Process procAD = new Process();
        procAD.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\dsa.msc";
        procAD.Start();
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Didn't open...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Start `mmc.exe` with the msc file as a parameter.

Comment: Works. Make that an answer and I'll accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways. I would suggest that you actually start the `mmc.exe` executable and give it the `msc` file as an argument. For example:

```
Process procAD = new Process();
procAD.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\mmc.exe";
procAD.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\dsa.msc";
procAD.Start();
```

You should also be able to do this, which is the same a double-clicking the file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\dsa.msc");
```